# Topographicmap.jpg convert to GPS readable

Tags: gps, maps, topography, jpg

I have topographic map 1:25000 and I want that map to be GPS readable. So, is there any program for maps that can import this .jpg extension and to track my position in platform of this my topo map ?
e.g. Soviet Military Maps app can only import .gpx, .kml, .kmz and .tcx. Or app Custom Maps can import .jpg but can only show Your lokation on/in that map, there is no routs, tracking, azimut etc

Comment: Are you trying to read this into a GPS unit (hand-held navigation device) or an app, because the answer may depend on the unit model or the app. Give a link to any apps, and say if they are Android/Mac/other because there's probably a whole load of things called "Custom Maps" out there.

Comment: Does your topographic map have got a world file?

Answer (score 0):

If you have your topographic map offline, and be able to your GPS show where are you in that map, try this:
In arcmap, you can save your map as a "georeferenced pdf" (File/Export Map/Save as type: PDF). Be sure to check the Options (In Advanced tab: Layers and attributes:"Export PDF layers only" and be sure to check "Export Map Georeference Information". 
Give your PDF a name and click "Save".

In order to load the PDF map into your GPS/Handheld device, use the software AVENZA, that allows you to download maps for offline use.